# which Technology to use MVC or angularjs for web application which contains search and applying

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I have new project requirement which contain search technologies and APPLY EOI for the selected which contains admin and user roles
Which technology to be used MVC or angularjs which one i best and Why

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You need to make a more expanded issue description, with some small snippets of code and by explicitly explaining bugs. I suggest you to visit the help center, in particular, to read how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the requirement. actually for getting the data you have to use server side that is mvc rest apis or node apis. so if you have large data you should use caching or if you have small data searching than you can load the data at client side and search easily.

in mvc the razer view pages code runs on server side and designer also needs to understand a little bit of razer syntax while angular runs client side so only html and js understanding required. Will you prefer your server side working to generate new html files, or let this work done by client side.

Comment: thanks for your comment.So you say i should go with web api with angular js i the rigth choice.Curently we have 20 tech may be increase in future

Comment: yes as the current technology trends, a lot of companies are using angular 2 or upper version with apis. If the answer solved your problem, you can close the question by clicking the check-mark next to this.